# AWS WAF and websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

Can anyone tell me if the AWS WAF supports websockets (wss if important)?

If so how is it costed given that it's a long lived connection and wouldn't seem to fit in to the per request style pricing I can see to the AWS WAF info page?

Thanks as always for the help!

Comment: I can't really answer your question, but might be able to provide some helpful observations. WAF really only seems to consider the initial request and (possibly the payload). This may mean that it does not care about the connection duration from a pricing/resource consumption point of view.